# Search Blogger in Objective-C

Tags: objective-c, gdata, blogger

I would like to implement a controller to search posts on a blog based in Blogger.

I have been using the GData API for other projects (generally for Youtube searches) but the GData API (especially that of Objective-C) severely lacks details explaining how to do this. (Please note that I only want results returned from a single individual blog!)

Any advice would be appreciated!

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Blogger support is now in the [Google APIs Client Library for Objective-C](http://code.google.com/p/google-api-objectivec-client/).  This replaces the older GData API.

The [GTLQueryBlogger](http://code.google.com/p/google-api-objectivec-client/source/browse/trunk/Source/Services/Blogger/Generated/GTLQueryBlogger.h) class includes the method blogger.posts.search (+queryForPostsSearchWithBlogId:)